# Set Appium framework on Mac to test Android apps

Tags: android, macos, appium-android

I would like to set Appium framework on Mac Sierra to test Android apps using Android Studio EDI.

Could you let me know how I can do it?

Thanks and regards,
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to find some help from here : [APPIUM AND SELENIUM WITH ANDROID STUDIO AND GRADLE](https://bitbar.com/appium-tip-20-executing-appium-tests-with-gradle/)